# Which female superhero with long brown hair is on this Marvel tie?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

I found a tie with a Marvel tag on the back, but have no idea who the character is on it.

Who is it?

[image: Necktie depicting masked female hero character in a teal super suit saying "hope you like my new costume!"]

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 39):

Echoing Daft's answer, this is [Sharon Ventura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharon_Ventura), AKA the She-Thing, AKA Ms. Marvel.

The picture seems to be a hand-drawn version of the frame below from [Fantastic Four #371](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_371)

[image]

Comment: Ey, there was never a solo title called She-Thing. Image [seems to be taken](https://images.app.goo.gl/LxQCRRoRZZkoARC46) from Fantastic Four #371

Comment: @RubioRic - You're not wrong. I'm baffled where I got that from...

Comment: @RubioRic - Make youraelf useful and find this one for me. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196722/name-of-the-green-character-on-this-marvel-t-shirt/196724#196724

Comment: Sure! :-) It looks from Starlin too

Answer (score 25):

#### It looks very much like [Sharon Ventura](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Sharon_Ventura_(Earth-616)) a.k.a She-Thing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Makes me think of Shadowcat.

[image: Shadowcat coming through wall]

Same mask, same darker curly hair, same color scheme. And she was mildly infamous for [changing her costumes](http://13thdimension.com/x-men-week-the-crazy-costumes-of-kitty-pryde/) several times in the early books as the "impetuous youth" of the group.

Comment: The Tie-Lady looks kind of _cosmic hero-ish_.

Comment: Good guess, no cigar.

Comment: @DCShannon: It was a guess from the gut. ^_^ I'll admit that I hadn't been aware just how many costumes Kitty *had* gone through.