# Name of the green character on this marvel t shirt

Tags: marvel, character-identification

I cannot remember the name of the green character on this Marvel t-shirt. I can't find her anywhere.

[image: T-shirt depicting four female characters]

Comment: I found [this image](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/93/59/22/93592243457a5996c114720db151ce81--the-snake-marvel-heroes.jpg), entitled "The Snake, Marvel Heroes", but can find no further information.

Comment: @OrangeDog - That image if you drag it to google suggests gamora. Not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks JohnP. This is her original incarnation.

Answer (score 16):

This is [Gamora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamora), as pictured in her original (and rather more revealing) comic guise.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Purely for the record, the other characters are [Black Widow](https://www.writeups.org/wp-content/uploads/Black-Widow-Marvel-Comics-Natalia-Romanova-3-c.jpg), [Mantis](https://www.writeups.org/wp-content/uploads/Mantis-Marvel-Comics-Avengers-Profile-b.jpg) and [The Scarlet Witch](https://www.writeups.org/wp-content/uploads/Scarlet-Witch-Marvel-Comics-Avengers-Early-j.jpg)